# Append label if condition meet in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have input box `txtRefreshInterval` which allow only integer.

```
<td><span class="sfFormlabel">Refresh Interval</span></td>
<td><input type="text"  id="txtRefreshInterval"/> </td>
```

I validate it like this.

```
 $('#txtRefreshInterval').keydown(function() {
                    if (isNaN($('#txtRefreshInterval').val())) {
                        //$("#lblError").html("<br/>Please Enter Integer Value.");
                        return false;

                    }
                });
```

It works fine.In html there is not any `lblEroor`.I want to append `lblError` if and only if input box have not integer through code.
append:

`<label id='lblError'>`

and display message.But I am not find correct way to append

`<label>`

after

`txtRefreshInterval`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#txtRefreshInterval').keydown(function() {
                    if (isNaN($('#txtRefreshInterval').val())) {
                         $(this).after('<label id='lblError'>Error</label>');
                        return false;

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have the lblError element exist on load as "display: none" and if the value is not a number, you show the error message (instead of the javascript dom manipulation)

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

Define the label element in html itself and insert error text to it directly.
Have your html like this:

```
<td><span class="sfFormlabel">Refresh Interval</span></td>
<td><input type="text"  id="txtRefreshInterval"/> </td>
<label id='lblError'></label>
```

In your jquery code, you can now directly insert html in label tag:

```
$("#lblError").html("<br/>Please Enter Integer Value.");
```

**Method 2**

You can use jquery .after() for this:

```
$('#txtRefreshInterval').after("<label id='lblError'>Please Enter Integer Value.</label>");
```

Answer (score 0):

i would prefer `keyup`

```
$('#txtRefreshInterval').keyup(function() {
                    if (isNaN($('#txtRefreshInterval').val())) {
                        $("#lblError").html("<br/>Please Enter Integer Value.")
                       .after($(this));
                        return false;

                    }
                });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Tfym9/2/)

**EDIT:**

```
$('#txtRefreshInterval').keyup(function() {
                    if (isNaN($('#txtRefreshInterval').val())) {
                        console.log("here");
                        $(this).after(
                        $("<span/>").html("<br/>Please Enter Integer Value.")
                        );
                        return false;

                    }
                });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tfym9/10/)

---

**yet another update** hide the error message when the input is correct

```
$('#txtRefreshInterval').keyup(function() {
                    if (isNaN($('#txtRefreshInterval').val())) {
                        console.log("here");
                        $(this).after(
                            $("<span/>",{id:'lblerr'}).html("<br/>Please Enter Integer Value.")
                        );
                        return false;
                    }
               if($("#lblerr"))
                  $("#lblerr").remove(); 
                });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tfym9/13/

Comment: How to append `label` there is not any `#lblError`.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i accept eiu165's ans he understand what i want.But i solve it with your ans means with `keyup`.Thanks a lot.